# ¿Por qué decimos "dos mil" y no "dos miles"?

Tags: gramática, plurales, números

Si escribimos un número grande en español, por ejemplo el 123456789, tenemos lo siguiente:

> Ciento veintitrés **millones** **cuatrocientos** cincuenta y seis **mil** **setecientos** ochenta y nueve.

Nótense las palabras en negrita:

- "Millones" y los que expresan "cientos" ("cuatrocientos", "setecientos") van en plural, dado que en cada caso hay varios millones y varios cientos.
- En cambio "mil" va en singular, aunque estamos expresando que hay varios miles.

¿Por qué usamos pues el singular de "mil" para expresar cifras aunque incluyan varios miles? ¿Hay algún motivo histórico para esto? ¿Se usó "miles" alguna vez?

Comment: Posiblemente porque mil no es sustantivo

Comment: @mdewey lo es en frases como "aquí hay varios miles de personas". Y en el caso de "aquí hay dos mil personas", ¿no debería concordar el adjetivo en número con "dos"?

Comment: seis mil vs seis millones, creo que mil y millones tienen la misma función dentro de la frase

Answer (score 2):

En este caso es un adjetivo numeral y se desaconseja el uso de "miles".

> - Se pospone a los cardinales que expresan unidades, decenas y centenas para formar los numerales correspondientes a su serie: dos mil, cuarenta mil, doscientos mil, etc.
> - Para expresar cantidades concretas, **se desaconseja el uso del sustantivo miles**, siendo mayoritario y preferible el empleo del adjetivo numeral mil; así, es mejor decir tres mil personas que tres miles de personas, mejor 3500 millones (tres mil quinientos millones), que 3,5 miles de millones, etc.
>
> Fuente: Puntos 1 y 4 de [la entrada del DPD para "mil"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=KSewKKH9vD6E0PSwQ8)

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.se. Esta contribución ganaría mucho si copiases en ella el contenido relevante del artículo enlazado. Así, no solo explicas en lugar de decir "la solución está el el artículo enlazado" sino que en caso de que la página enlazada desaparezca el contenido queda aquí (vamos, que es "buena práctica")

Comment: eso fue lo que hice en mi frase. Lo mas importante es que es un adjetivo numeral y se desaconseja el uso de "miles".

Comment: Mejor hago un edit, ya que un ejemplo vale más que mil palabras, y así muestro a lo que me refería: Copiar las partes relevantes del artículo enlazado que explican cómo llegas a esa conclusión de 'En este caso es un adjetivo numeral y se desaconseja el uso de "miles".', que en la versión original era lo único que tenías, aparte del enlace. Recuerda que hacer buen uso del formato también te ayuda a resaltar aspectos clave de tu contribución.

Answer (score -1):

Es una excepción de tantas que hay que aprender en el español. Curiosamente, en el inglés se hace lo mismo. Debe ser una regla que distingue el contexto de usar números específicos o nociones de cantidad.

six **thousand** five hundred seven para leer 6507. Pero pensamos en **thousands** de cosas.